# NonUniqueObjectException Hibernate Exception in Update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am getting below exception while updating the value in a table.

My code is :

```
DAOFactory.TableName.update(obj);
```

If I am saving a new value and then updating the same value, I am getting below exception :

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session.
```

I checked on net, we need to clear the session after saving.
But since I am using DAOFactory how can I clear the session. Please help me

Comment: 'If I am saving a new value and then updating the same value' - could you please show us the relevant code?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? In most cases you should be running inside a transaction and modified objects should be persisted to the database automatically, no need to call update()

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easier solution is to refresh the object before updating it

```
Session.refresh(obj)
```